# CmakeList: Dependencies for static libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, dependencies, static-libraries

Let's imagine we have two static libraries which are separate projects:

```
################################################
# Logger library ###############################

set(Logger_INCLUDE_DIRS Logger/include)
set(Logger_LIBRARIES Logger)

add_library(Logger STATIC
    ${PROJECT_HEADERS}
    ${PROJECT_RESOURCES}
    ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    ${MISC}
    )
target_include_directories(Logger
    PUBLIC
        include
        )

################################################
# Utils library ################################

add_library(Utils STATIC
    ${PROJECT_HEADERS}
    ${PROJECT_RESOURCES}
    ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    ${MISC}
    )
```

`Utils` library depends on `Logger` library for logging

**Which of these ways will be right to provide** `Logger` **sources for** `Utils` **library or they are both incorrect and I need to use another one**

I have two options here, first one is to provide only *.h file, as far as understood it is enough for static library:

```
target_include_directories(Utils
    PUBLIC
        include
        ${Logger_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        )
```

The other one is to use `target_link_libraries`, as far as I understood *.h files are linked too but in general we do not need to link one static library with another one and this is redundant:

```
target_link_libraries(Utils
    ${Logger_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

Comment: Second is better, as one day you can switch `Logger` into shared library and there will be no problems with that other than switching library type. Redundancy you are talking about doesn't cost you anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `target_link_libraries` whenever one library/executable target uses another library target. Do not think about redudancy of linking static libraries.

In CMake, linking **targets** is much more than simple linking libraries. Large part of CMake is propagating libraries properties when linking. Just use that.

---

Also, if you will decide to transform your STATIC library into SHARED, using `target_link_libraries` provide no additional actions in such transformation.